# Frames in HTML 5

Tags: html, frame, w3c

I realize that `frame` is removed in HTML5, and there must be great reason that they do it.

I wonder how to implement the same feature in HTML5.

Comment: what do you need them for? you can reload parts of the page using ajax.

Comment: @Mark I do know that I can use AJAX, but it's really just a simple one-page project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use `<iframe>` or try working with `<object>` tags.  I used `<object>` once on a project that had to be HTML4 strict and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You can still use an `iframe`. Would that be fine?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/iframe

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/144515/why-were-frames-deprecated-in-html5-but-not-iframes

Comment: I do know that I can still use iframe, but it gives me a very ugly border between two iframes. Anyway I can avoid them?

Comment: That would be called CSS. Specifically, the `border` style.